# I am trying to setup Icingas web setup but getting error

Tags: mysql, icinga

I am trying to setup Icinga2. Here's what I am doing. I have installed mysql db on one server and Icinga on other. Up until now everything is fine. But When I try to set up web for Icinga before finish tab it throws following error:

Unable to create account "icinga_admin". An error occured:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'icinga.icingaweb_user' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   icingaweb_user.name FROM icingaweb_user.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks